# How do I view or update a single record from a database list with a button in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

First I select all records from a table and list them in my GUI.
Every row has two buttons next to them, one for deleting the record and one for viewing/updating that specific record in a pop up screen. I have tried a couple of different things, but I seem to be unable to fetch the information from the specific records I want to view/update. I have tried with adding textvariables to the button etc.

My question is, how do you view and/or update a specific row out of a list off all rows from my table?

```
def Show_Keylog_Records(self):
            data = self.Select_Keylog_Records()
            for index, dat in enumerate(data):
                Row_ID = index
                Key_Num = dat[0]
                self.Row_ID = Frame(self.Result_Frame, bg='#333')
                Label(self.Row_ID, text=dat[0]).pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                Label(self.Row_ID, text=dat[1]).pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                Label(self.Row_ID, text=dat[2]).pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                Label(self.Row_ID, text=dat[3]).pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                Button(self.Row_ID, text='view', textvariable=Row_ID, command=self.View_Keylog_Record).pack(side=RIGHT)
                Button(self.Row_ID, text='Delete', command=self.Delete_Keylog_Record).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
                self.Row_ID.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, pady=3)


def Select_Keylog_Records(self):
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM KeyLog")
        return c.fetchall() 

def View_Keylog_Record(self):
        Record = (Row_ID.get(),)
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM KeyLog WHERE index=?', Record)
        print c.fetchone()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to communicate to `View_Keylog_Record` which DB row you are interested in?

Comment: The question i'm asking is: how do i pass the index (or any other data) of any row that i want changed from Show_Keylog_Records to View_Keylog_Record

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to pass the `index` to the function. If so, change the Button instantiation like this:

```
Button(self.Row_ID, text='view', command=lambda index=index: self.View_Keylog_Record(index)).pack(side=RIGHT)
```

**OR**

```
Button(self.Row_ID, text='view', command=functools.partial(self.View_Keylog_Record, index)).pack(side=RIGHT)
```

Note you will have to `import functools` to use the second option.

Make a similar change to the delete button and then modify the functions like this:

```
def View_Keylog_Record(self, index):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM KeyLog WHERE index=?', (index,))
    print c.fetchone()
```

Make the corresponding change to Delete_Keylog_Record and see if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, i get an error (c.execute('SELECT * FROM KeyLog WHERE index=?', index)sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error. When i printed the output of index it always printed 9 no matter which button i pressed (i've got 11 rows, so its weird that it selects 9)

Comment: @SparkBarisart Sorry, my bad. You have to bind the variable in the lambda. There is also `functools.partial`, I have added an example of that.

Comment: Oh, also `cursor.execute` expects paramters to be in an iterable. So instead of passing `index` as the second argument to `c.execute` pass `(index,)`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It worked but only when i passed the index as (index, ). I'll have a read on the functools as they seem very handy! Thanks again!

Comment: I needed to make a small change because it saw my first row as row 0 (while when i displayed it,m it woulds say the first row was row 1)                             `def View_Keylog_Record(self, index):
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM KeyLog WHERE rowid=?', (index+1,))
            Test = c.fetchone()
            print (Test)`